# Android: NoSuchMethodError : getFrameAtTime

Tags: android, media

My sdk is 2.1
I new a MediaMetadataRetriever.java in the package android.media
It works when i call captureFrame();
But when i use 
    bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(20); 
(which is added manually)it shuts down.
The log: ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime

MediaMetadataRetriever.java :

```
 public Bitmap getFrameAtTime(long timeUs) {
        return getFrameAtTime(timeUs, OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

The method android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime is available since API Level 10 which means since 2.3.3.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html

Comment: It does work when i call captureFrame() (which is available since API 8)

Comment: But in your self made method you call getFrameAtTime(timeUs, OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
Did you created that method as well?

Comment: Yes, i did...  what i call in the self made method is getFrameAtTime(timeUs) which is created in MediaMetadataRetriever.java

Comment: Did you try to make it run under API Level 10. I am pretty sure he cant find your MediaMetadataRetriever. Either because you selected the wrong API level, or if you included it yourself, you included not everything need or set the wrong path.

Comment: I tried it on API Level 10, but it shut down either. I download the src 2.3.3 from the official website, but i found no MediaMetadataRetriever.java. Do you have any idea where it is? or how to realize the method: getFrameAtTime(timeUs) ? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Then you downloaded the wrong one. In my API Level 10 Android.jar there is the MediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: would you please tell me where it is? I downloaded 2.3.2 and 2.3.3, but still can not find it. Thx~

Comment: Follow these instruction to get started with Android and add other platforms.http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html